# Model null after postback using EditorFor<string>

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using an Editor Template, the syntax in the view looks like this:

```
Html.EditorFor(m => m.Email)
```

The string editor template looks like this:

```
@{
   var o = ViewData.ModelMetadata;
} 

@model string

@Html.TextBox(o.PropertyName,
              this.Model,
              new { @class="textinput-single-line", placeholder = o.Watermark })
```

The problem is that upon postback, model.Email is null no matter what I type in the TextBox. Why is the text box value not properly bound to the model?

**Edit:** Here's the HTML output

```
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Log in Form</legend>
          <ol>
            <li>
              <div class="editor-for">
                <label class="label-single-line" for="Email_Email">Email</label>
                <input class="textinput-single-line" id="Email_Email" name="Email.Email" placeholder="" type="text" value=""/>
                <div class="clearboth"/>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="editor-for">
                <span class="label-single-line"/>
                <input class="tickbox-single-line" id="RememberMe_RememberMe" name="RememberMe.RememberMe" type="checkbox" value="true"/>
                <input name="RememberMe.RememberMe" type="hidden" value="false"/>
                <label class="label-tickbox" for="RememberMe_RememberMe">Remember me?</label>
                <div class="clearboth"/>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ol>
          <input type="submit" value="Log in"/>
        </fieldset>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `Html.TextBoxFor` in the template instead of `Html.TextBox`?

Comment: @Gromer what expression would I pass as an argument of Html.TextBoxFor?

Comment: `@Html.TextBoxFor(s => s, new { @class="textinput-single-line", placeholder = o.Watermark })`.  `s` is the string that was sent in.  Try that out, pretty sure that's the syntax you'd want. Don't have my code on hand that used some simple editor templates like this.

Comment: @LuisFerrao `Email.Email` and `RememberMe.RememberMe` seem strange. Can you include your model class as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String.Empty` or `""` in your editor template. The view engine will figure out the correct name for you.

```
@Html.TextBox(String.Empty,
              this.Model,
              new { @class="textinput-single-line", placeholder = o.Watermark })
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not fix my issue, and the 'figured out' name is exactly the same as it was before.

Comment: Can you post the generated html?

Comment: This was indeed the problem. I don't know what happened the first time I tested it but this time around it worked. Is this the best practice in Editor Templates? To let it figure out the name on its own?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. But I can't find a reference to back it up. I'll update my answer if I find one.